# Operator cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'DayOfWeek'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a website that has checkboxes that read Monday - Friday and the user is able to select none, one or more than one.

CDay list contains the days of the week: Monday - Friday. What I want to do is take in the current day of the week and return true if the user has chosen that day

list code:

```
 public List<CDay> days { get; set; }
    public CDay()
    {
     Name = string.Empty; // Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday
     Selected = false; //will be true if user has selected this checkbox
    }
```

my logic:
// is the current day the same for any of the days the user has chosen

```
private bool currentDayOfTheWeek (DateTime day, List <CDay> days)
        {
          System.DayOfWeek wk = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek;
        
          for (int i = 0; i < days.Count; i++)
          {

            if ( days[i].Selected.Equals(true) && wk) 
                 {
                     return true;
                 }
              }
            return false;
          }
```

My problem is that this statement: days[i].Selected.Equals(true) && wk gives me an "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'DayOfWeek'.. not sure how I would go about this error?

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
if ( days[i].Selected.Equals(true) && wk)
```

is interpreted by the compiler as

```
if ( days[i].Selected.Equals(true) && wk == true)
```

This, however, doesn't make sense - `wk` is of type `DayOfWeek`, an enumeration that assigns a number (and `int`, internally) to each day of the week. Boolean values are not part of the enumeration and the compiler doesn't know how to convert your `wk` value to `true` or `false` so it throws that error.

To fix this, you need to explicitly specify what condition `wk` should pass - reading your code, it could perhaps equal to the selected day in the `days` collection?

Answer (score 1):

This should get you the day as a string "Monday" or "Tuesday" etc:

`var dayOfWeek = DateTime.Today.ToString("dddd");`

Then your check can become:

```
for (int i = 0; i < days.Count; i++)
{
    if (days[i].Selected.Equals(true) && dayOfWeek == days[i].Name) 
    {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: I do this but in my code i get an error saying "cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to System.Collections.GenericList<>" i do "return true"

Comment: You definitely have the code written as above now?

Comment: yes i do .. not sure why this error arised

Comment: Are you sure the error is in the amended method above and not in the code which is calling this method? Do you get a line number where the error is at?

Answer (score 0):

fix the class and the code

```
private bool currentDayOfTheWeek(DateTime day, List<CDay> days)
{
    var dow = day.DayOfWeek.ToString();

    foreach (var d in days)
        if (d.Selected && dow == d.Name) return true;

    return false;
}

public class CDay
{
    public string Name {get; set;} = string.Empty; // Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday
    public bool Selected {get; set;} // false by default, will be true if user has selected this checkbox
}
```

or using LINQ

```
private bool currentDayOfTheWeek(DateTime day, List<CDay> days)
{
    var dow = day.DayOfWeek.ToString();

    return days.Any(d => d.Selected && dow == d.Name);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Nice Easy And Simple**

```
private bool currentDayOfTheWeek (DateTime day, List <CDay> days)
{
    System.DayOfWeek wk = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek;
    foreach (var item in days)
    {
        if (item.Selected && item.Name == wk.ToString()) 
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Note:**

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and
> 'DayOfWeek

*Means*

`DayOfWeek` is an `Enum` and you compare it with `Boolean` type

**Resolution**

Convert `Enum` to `string` and then compare it with the day